# AWS Cognito Forgot Password

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, promise, amazon-cognito

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

// Send confirmation code to user's email or phone
Auth.forgotPassword(username)
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Collect confirmation code and new password, then
Auth.forgotPasswordSubmit(username, code, new_password)
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I want to catch when a user's phone number or email is not verified, so I can either resend the verification code or let the user know.

I thought I saw somewhere in the documentation that amplify should throw an error if the phone/email aren't verified but that is not the case. It will return that it sent the code to the provided phone/email by user but they will never receive this code (I'm assuming cause it's not verified).

They actually never receive a code from `.forgotPassword` and from my end (or in the code) the response `data` makes it seem like the code was sent. But `.forgotPasswordSubmit` won't work without the code.

How can I catch if the user's phone/email isn't verified or how to catch if they actually receive a code?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this problem . it's based in getting a value of email_verified or phone_number_verified attribute  before calling forgot password method ,
if the value is false tell the user he must verify his email firstly (here call verifyUserAttribute method and pass email as attribute then the user will receive confirmation code to verify his email
after that you can call forgotpassword method )

I use aws java sdk  in server side https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/cognitoidentityprovider/CognitoIdentityProviderClient.html  (you can apply the idea in your app)

**example**

1 - if the user is logged in (user has access key)
(like if user is logged in and he want to change his password but he detected he forgot it )

```
   GetUserRequest getUserRequest = GetUserRequest.builder().accessToken("access key ").build();

   GetUserResponse getUserResponse = cognitoIdentityProviderClient.getUser(getUserRequest);
  

        
    Map<String, String>  userAttributesMap = new HashMap<>();
     for (AttributeType attributeType : attributeTypesList) {
            
      userAttributesMap.put(attributeType.name(), attributeType.value());
      }
        
      boolean isEmailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(userAttributesMap.get("email_verified"));

      if(isEmailVerified ){
          // call forgotpassword method 
       }else{
           //tell  user his email i s not verified and call verifiyuserAttribute method with email as attribute
     }
```

2 - if the user is logged in (user not has access key)  you can user AdminGetUserRequest
(like when user try to login but he forgot his password )

```
      AdminGetUserRequest getUserRequest = 
      AdminGetUserRequest
         .builder()
         .username("username")
         .userPoolId("user pool id ")
         .build();


      AdminGetUserResponse getUserResponse = 
           cognitoIdentityProviderClient
           .adminGetUser(getUserRequest);

      List<AttributeType> attributeTypesList = getUserResponse.userAttributes();
        
     Map<String, String>  userAttributesMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (AttributeType attributeType : attributeTypesList) {
            
   userAttributesMap.put(attributeType.name(), attributeType.value());
     }
        
      boolean isEmailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(userAttributesMap.get("email_verified"));

     if(isEmailVerified ){
        // call forgotpassword method 
      }else{
         //tell  user his email i s not verified and call verifiyuserAttribute method with email as attribute
     }
```

Hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible.
See the documentation for further information:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ForgotPassword.html

Although the API should give us an exception about unverified emails for certain usernames when you call the `ForgotPassword` endpoint, I don't receive any of it.

> If neither a verified phone number nor a verified email exists, an InvalidParameterException is thrown.

So it's still like a blackbox where the outcome is uncertain.

The only thing you can probably do as a developer is to give your users a prominent hint to verify their mail adress upon their first login.

Comment: You are not receiving because you have the "Prevent user existence errors" set to true, if it's set to false Cognito will throw an error as expected.